# Dropdown Menu With Negative Z-index Getting Hidden Under Element

Tags: css, position, css-position, z-index

I have a dropdown menu using CSS transition for animation and `z-index: -1` to hide in behind the main nav. This works fine if the nav doesn't have any other element right below it, however because of the `z-index`, once I put a section with a solid background, the dropdown goes underneath. Of course if I change to a higher `z-index` the dropdown will go above the main nav.

Besides changing the element directly below (in this case `section`) to `position: absolute; z-index: -2` how can I achieve the desired effect? I would prefer to only alter css properties of the nav class and not the section if possible.

Here's the [project for reference](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/wvadVag).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `section` position value to `relative`

```
section{
  ...
  position:relative;
}
```

On `li:hover` consider playing with `z-index` as below.

```
.navUl li:hover ul {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: With `position:relative;` it does stay above the section, however once you hover over the dropdown nav, the nav slides back up. And if possible, I would prefer to change css properties of the `nav` class and not `section`

Comment: Adding the `z-index: 1` to `.navUl li:hover ul` will cause the dropdown to initially start above the main nav.